# Reordering frameworks rules of thumb?

Tags: xcode, frameworks

I saw in xCode that I can reorder the frameworks. I assume that it has influence on the order of loading them on run time ?

My questions :

- What is the direct influences on the app (Speed of loading etc ?)
- Are there any rules of thumb for the reordering ?

Thanks,
Shani

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't found issues related to the order of frameworks. The only consequence I could think of is the resulting order of warning/error messages if there is any.

In the end, I went into grouping the frameworks from same origin together (those from Apple first), and then ordering them alphabetically.